# cabal test does not print executable output

Tags: testing, stdout, cabal

I have a cabal package for which I have a `test-suite` set up using the `exitcode-stdio-1.0` type, like so:

When I run it using `cabal test`, cabal does not print the standard output/standard error of the executable; it only prints its own logging information:

```
$ cabal test

Running 1 test suites...
Test suite test-foo: RUNNING...
Test suite test-foo: PASS
Test suite logged to: dist/test/foo-0.0.1-test-foo.log
1 of 1 test suites (1 of 1 test cases) passed.
$
```

The output that I want is in that log file:

```
$ cat dist/test/foo-0.0.1-test-fo.log 
Test suite test-foo: RUNNING...
HUnit group 1:
  Expected connect: [OK]

         Test Cases  Total      
 Passed  1           1          
 Failed  0           0          
 Total   1           1          
Test suite test-foo: PASS
Test suite logged to: dist/test/foo-0.0.1-test-foo.log
$
```

**How do I get cabal to print this output to its own standard output?** I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for this post. I would have thought directing to standard output would be the most common use case.

Comment: For new-build: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488620/how-can-i-stream-test-results-with-cabal-new-test

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using Cabal new-test (defualt on Cabal 3+):

```
$ cabal new-test --test-show-details=streaming
```

Older Cabal versions allow the output to be streamed using:

```
$ cabal test --show-details=streaming
```

> --show-details=*filter*
>
> Determines if the results of individual test cases are shown on the
> terminal. May be *always* (always show), *never* (never show), *failures* (show only failed results), or *streaming* (show all results in real time).

Read more in the [Cabal User Guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html).

Answer (score 4):

There has been a new way for a few months, and tests results are even written to stdout on the file, not flushed at the end

```
cabal test --show-details=streaming
```

Answer (score -1):

When using `exitcode-stdio-1.0` cabal will only report the test log if the test program returns an exit code (explictly "fails").  A solution would be to make your test program return an error code when any of the tests fail:

```
import System.Exit (exitFailure, exitSuccess)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- runTests
  if result
    then exitSuccess
    else exitFailure

runTests :: IO Bool
runTests = do
  ...
  return True/False
```

You only need that when writing a "manual" testing program: most test reporting frameworks (e.g.: [tasty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty), [test-framework](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/test-framework), [hspec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Hspec)) already do to that automatically.

If you really want to *always* see the results, you can always use either:

- `cabal test --log=/dev/stdout` (given in another answer)
- `exitFailure` at the end of execution