# How can I stream test results with cabal new-test?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-new

Using `cabal test`, you're able to stream results with `cabal test --show-details=streaming`.

I can't find a comparable option for `cabal new-test`. Is it possible to stream results using `new-test`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran into this an hour ago myself!

The `--show-details` flag is not yet supported by `new-test`: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4766

The discussion in the bug report indicate that maybe `--show-details` was a misfeature anyways, and it should always just stream.

Answer (score 4):

As of [PR 5455](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/5455) (probably available since Cabal-install 3, see [changelog](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/c901542c1d658ae949e6a8c922ab87a56e26b223/Cabal/ChangeLog.md#3000-mikhail-glushenkov-august-2019)), you can use `--test-show-details=streaming`:

```
~/hackage-server $ cabal test --enable-tests --test-show-details=streaming ReverseDependenciesTest
Building test suite 'ReverseDependenciesTest' for hackage-server-0.5.1..
Test suite ReverseDependenciesTest: RUNNING...
ReverseDependenciesTest
  with set [beeline->mtl] and querying for mtl, we get beeline:                                        OK
  revPackageName selects only latest version, even if it has no dependency on chosen package:          OK
  revPackageId does select old version when queried with old reverse dependency:                       OK
  revPackageName can find multiple packages:                                                           OK
  with set [beeline->mtl->base, lens->mtl->base], revPackageFlat 'base' finds [beeline, lens, mtl]:    OK
  with set [beeline->mtl->base, lens->mtl->base], revPackageStats 'base' return 1,3:                   OK
  with set [beeline->mtl->base, lens->mtl->base], queryReverseDeps 'base' return [mtl],[beeline,lens]: OK

All 7 tests passed (0.01s)
```